# Strange behaviour from REQUEST_FILENAME?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using MAMP, with a virtual-host based setup creating a '.dev' tld for working on.
My site's .htaccess uses mod_rewrite like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(butchers|news|recipes)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /$1.php?s=$2 [L,QSA]
```

My website features a directory of butcher's shops. The list view is displayed by `butchers.php` accessible at `butchers`. The detail view is displayed by `butchers.php?s=some-butcher-name` accessible at `butchers/some-butcher-name`.
The same mechanism works for the News and Recipes sections, as you can see.

Ok here's the thing: *this used to work*. It worked fine, and then I rebooted my system some time after upgrading MAMP and now it gives me an Internal server error. I assume I've gone from Apache 1.x to 2.x; I had to redo my vhost config after upgrading but everything else is vanilla (same as last time) *except* that I have disabled `MultiViews`. The mod_rewrite log looks like this (first few columns truncated)

```
[perdir /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/] add path info postfix: /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/butchers -> /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/butchers/example-butcher
[perdir /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/butchers/example-butcher -> butchers/example-butcher
[perdir /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'butchers/example-butcher'
[perdir /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/] RewriteCond: input='/Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/butchers' pattern='!-d' => matched
[perdir /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/] RewriteCond: input='/Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/butchers' pattern='!-f' => matched
[perdir /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/] RewriteCond: input='/Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/butchers.php' pattern='-f' => matched
[perdir /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/] rewrite 'butchers/example-butcher' -> 'butchers/example-butcher.php'
[perdir /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/] add per-dir prefix: butchers/example-butcher.php -> /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/butchers/example-butcher.php
[perdir /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/] trying to replace prefix /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/ with /
strip matching prefix: /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/butchers/example-butcher.php -> butchers/example-butcher.php
add subst prefix: butchers/example-butcher.php -> /butchers/example-butcher.php
[perdir /Users/myusername/Sites/dev/sitename/] internal redirect with /butchers/example-butcher.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Here's my understanding of what's happening:

- My UA asks for `butchers/example-butcher`
- **When REQUEST_FILENAME is used in the RewriteCond, it outputs the path with only `butchers`, not `butchers/example-butcher`**
- This passes, because `butchers.php` is real
- Rewrite is allowed to append '.php', as per the RewriteRule
- When it appends, it appends it to the *original* request, `butchers/example-butcher`
- The internal redirect restarts the loop with `butchers/example-butcher.php`

Then process starts again with the same problem - that the RewriteCond tests this weird, incomplete version of the path, but *operates on* the correct path. This happens ten times, accumulating more and more `.php`'s, before apache hits the limit and issues a 500.

- request `butchers/example-butcher`
- is `butchers.php` a real file? yes!
- append `.php`
- request `butchers/example-butcher.php`
- is `butchers.php` a real file? yes!
- append `.php`
- request `butchers/example-butcher.php.php`
- ... and so on

So, I can see **why** there is a loop, and why it wants to keep adding `.php` to itself, I just don't understand why REQUEST_FILENAME only ever gives the first level of the path. I can't find any documentation that says that this is prescribed behaviour.

Any ideas? I've already burned a whole workday on this :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` variable isn't simply the requested URI mapped to a single file/directory. When you have a request like:

```
/foo/bar/something
```

And you have either the files:

```
/foo.php
/foo/bar.php
/foo/bar/something.php
```

the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

**will be true** because mod_rewrite also accounts for PATH_INFO. If you have one of those php files, then mod_rewrite will attempt to be clever and figure out if a requested URI is actually within the requested URI path and add the `.php` to *that* path node instead of at the very end. To *strictly* check if the request + `.php` exists, you need to do:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
```